# Argsort all elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, sorting

Is it possible to argsort a multidimensional array where all the values are taken into account (all axis are taken into account)? For example,

```
A = [[[4,11],[7,5]],
     [[6,1],[8, 9]]] 

argsort(A)=[[[1,7],[4,2]],
            [[3,0],[5,6]]]
```

Comment: I'm sure that it would be if you could provide an explanation of what you want.  For example, how does any kind of sort result in different numbers than originally in `A`?

Comment: I'm sorry if it is unclear. I would like to sort the values in A and get the indices in the argsort array. For example, 1 in A is the smallest, so it gets the value 0, then the second smallest value is 4, and gets value of 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[4, 11], [7, 5]], [[6, 1], [8, 9]]])

# First, make a flat argsort
sorting = A.flatten().argsort()  # array([5, 0, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1])

# Let's create an array to gather the result
result = np.zeros(A.size, dtype=int)  # array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

# Now we place ordinal values at the indices provided by the arg sorting
result[sorting] = np.arange(A.size)  # array([1, 7, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6])

# Finally, we shape it back as the original
result = result.reshape(A.shape)  # array([[[1, 7], [4, 2]], [[3, 0], [5, 6]]])
```

Edited after Scott Hunter's remark on duplicates:
The above will always provide a *sorting*, meaning that duplicates won't have the same index returned. In case of duplicates, the order of the original array is used for untying. For example:

```py
B = np.array([[[4, 11], [7, 5]], [[7, 1], [11, 9]]])
sorting = B.flatten().argsort()  # array([5, 0, 3, 2, 4, 7, 1, 6])
result = np.zeros(B.size, dtype=int)  # array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
result[sorting] = np.arange(B.size)  # array([1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 5])
result = result.reshape(B.shape)  # array([[[1, 6], [3, 2]], [[4, 0], [7, 5]]])
```

In case you would rather have duplicate values having the same index, a ranking-like approach is to be preferred over a sorting (and this si actually easier).

```py
B = np.array([[[4, 11], [7, 5]], [[7, 1], [11, 9]]])

# Get the ranks
_, ranks = np.unique(B, return_inverse=True)

# Reshape to get the result
result = ranks.reshape(B.shape)  # array([[[1, 5], [3, 2]], [[3, 0], [5, 4]]])
```

Note 1: This second method gives the same result as the first one for array `A`.

Note 2: Those are not really "ranks", properly speaking, but sequential indices eventually shared by duplicate values. A proper ranking-based solution would give something like `array([[[1, 6], [3, 2]], [[3, 0], [6, 5]]])`. Unfortunately, as far as I know, numpy doesn't offer actual straightforward ranking, you would need to implement it. So, without more information, I'll keep it in this "rankish" state for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Will this properly handle duplicates (for some reasonable definition of "properly")?

Comment: @ScottHunter good point! I edited my answer to cover that.